# Can "manage to" be separated?

Tags: infinitives, syntax, complementation, to-infinitive

I have often seen the "manage to" combination used with the two parts adjacent to each other.
Can I write "I managed after one year to get a car"? Or do I have to write "After one year, I managed to..."?

Comment: Yes, separating it as you did is OK. If I could explain why, I would Answer rather than Comment.

Answer (score 1):

There is a relatively high number of places on the Web that discuss the possibility to split a compound verb (I suppose we can treat "manage to get" as one) with an adverb (or an adverb phrase like your "after one year").

Opinions differ.  In some situations the compound verb has much tighter coupling, like when perfect tenses are formed or with modal verbs "can" or "must".

Based on the amount of material available and the conclusions different authors make there I two reasons for which ***it may or may not be OK*** to write as you did:

> I **managed** *after one year* **to get** a car.

First reason, if you **treat** "managed to get" as a *compound verb*, Fowler reportedly allows placing an adverb *right after* an auxiliary verb:

> The books **are** *frequently* **published** on that subject.

So, in your case "managed" is auxiliary, "after one year" is an adverb.

Second reason, if you **don't treat** "managed to get" as a *compound verb*, but instead treat "to get" as an **object** of the verb "managed", then it's ***not OK*** because the *adverb* should never go between the **verb** and its ***direct object***

> He **climbed** *swiftly* ***the fence***. (*ugh!*)

ought to be

> He *swiftly* **climbed** ***the fence***.

or

> He **climbed** ***the fence*** *swiftly*.

---

I personally lean towards the latter interpretation of your sentence.  "to get" is the **direct object** of the verb "manage".  So, you ought to write as you suggested

> After one year, I managed to get a car

or put the adverb after the object

> I managed to get a car after one year.